# Pass C++ vector of unique_ptr<T> without passing ownership

Tags: c++, c++11, move, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I have a class `Outer` which contains an `Inner` member and **owns** a vector of unique_ptr elements:

```
using Elements = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Element>>;

class Outer
{
    void call()
    {
        _inner.aMethod(_vec);
    }

    Inner _inner;
    Elements _vec;   // This should remain the owner of each Element
};
```

`Inner` receives the vector of unique_ptr elements and it transfers ownership to it's own vector class member:

```
class Inner
{
    public:
    Inner() = default;
    ~Inner() = default;

    void aMethod(Elements& vec)
    {
        _vec = std::move(vec);
    }

    private:

    Elements _vec;  // This is a vector of unique_ptr but I don't want this class to own the memory
};
```

I stupidly used `std::move()` because otherwise the compiler complained I was trying to call a deleted function (probably the copy constructor) on each vector element.

I have an illegal memory access and I believe it is because both classes think they own the vector elements and one has tried to delete an already-deleted `Element`.

How do I have `Outer` owning the memory and just pass the elements to `Inner` to use (not take ownership)?

Comment: std::unique_ptr cannot be duplicated in any way. If it's moved, ownership is passed. Use shared_ptr instead.

Comment: Inner could store a reference or a (raw) pointer to the vector in outer rather than its own copy.  (As presumably all the Inner instances are own by an Outer, this does not seem risky.  Of course, be careful copying Outer objects...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have two `std::unique_ptr`s pointing to the same object.  `unique_ptr` implies *unique* ownership.

If you need ownership to be shared, use `std::shared_ptr`s instead.  In your example, it should be a drop-in replacement, just change the `using` declaration:

```
using Elements = std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Element>>;
```

---

If you don't want `Inner` objects to own the objects pointed to by its `_vec` member, then it should be a vector of raw pointers:

```
class Outer
{
    void call()
    {
        std::vector<Element*> observer;
        std::transform(_vec.begin(), _vec.end(), std::back_inserter(observer),
                       [](std::unique_ptr<Element>& el) { return el.get(); });
        _inner.aMethod(observer);
    }

    //...
};

class Inner
{
    // ...

    void aMethod(std::vector<Element*> vec)
    {
        _vec = std::move(vec);
    }

private:
    std::vector<Element*> _vec;
};
```

Of course, doing this would mean that you run the risk of leaving `_vec`'s elements dangling if `Outer` frees any of the `Element`s it owns without updating any `Inner` objects that are pointing to them.  You could partially mitigate that risk by storing a pointer to the `Outer` object instead of storing pointers directly to the `Element`s:

```
class Outer
{
    void call()
    {
        _inner.aMethod(this);
    }

    //...
};

class Inner
{
    // ...

    void aMethod(Outer* outer)
    {
        outer_ = outer;
    }

private:
    Outer* outer_;
};
```

`Inner` would then only access its `Element`s via the `Outer` object (you could make `Inner` a `friend` of `Outer` if necessary).  This still leaves the possibility that an `Inner` object could outlive the `Outer` object it points to, but it does reduce the risk somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

If Inner is supposed to access the same vector but not own it, why not let Inner keep a reference to the vector in Outer given the fact that they have the same life cycle?

```
class Inner
{
    public:
    Inner(Elements& vec):_vec(vec) {}
    ~Inner() = default;

    private:

    Elements& _vec;  // This is a reference to vector of unique_ptr, no ownership
};
```